# Tikz design garden

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can you help me create this picture that represents part of a garden 
in tikz?

[image]

Comment: Any reason for using `TikZ`? You can use any other program to draw it and include the result as a graphic.

Comment: What did you try so far? And why did you not bother to accept any of the nice answers to the other questions you asked so far?

Comment: @Igansi, I prefer Tikz.

Comment: @marmot, I didn't see something similar to start with and if I have one example I can draw a lot of others plans.

Comment: @HoudaAraj IMHO, using `TikZ` in such free-drawing context is less practical than using other vector graphics softwares such as Inkscape...

Answer (score 6):

All the things can be found in the pgfmanual, you only need to combine them. This code gives you a start, you need to tune the contours yourself unless you find another one who is willing to do it for you.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw[smooth] plot coordinates{(0,2)(6,2.6)(9,6)(9.5,8)};
\draw (0,7) .. controls ++(2,0.1) .. (2.2,8) coordinate[pos=1/3] (y1)
coordinate[pos=2/3] (y2);
\draw (0,5) .. controls ++(1.6,0.2) .. (y1) coordinate[pos=0.3] (y3);
\draw (0,3.5) .. controls ++(1.3,0.2) .. (y3) coordinate[pos=0.3] (y4);
\draw (0,2) .. controls ++(1.3,0.2) .. (y4);
\draw (5.5,8) .. controls ++(-1,-1.4) .. (y2) coordinate[pos=0.2] (y5);
\draw (7.5,8) .. controls ++(-0.6,-1.4) .. (y5) coordinate[pos=0.2] (y6);
\draw (9,6) .. controls ++(-1.8,0.5) .. (y6);
\draw (3,3.8) circle (1.6 and 1);
\draw (3,3.8) circle (0.6 and 0.45);
\draw[rotate around={35:(6.5,4.6)}] (6.5,4.5) circle (1.6 and 0.6);
\draw[rotate around={35:(6.5,4.6)}] (5.8,4.5) circle (0.6 and 0.3);
\draw[rotate around={35:(6.5,4.6)}] (7.2,4.5) circle (0.6 and 0.3);
\draw (5,6) circle (1 and 0.6);
\node[draw,ellipse,text width=1.5cm,font=\tiny\sffamily,inner sep=0pt,minimum
height=1.2cm] at (2.8,5.8){unreadable 
text};
\node[text width=1.5cm,font=\tiny\sffamily,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north] at 
(3.5,8){unreadable text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This snippet shows three possible ways of obtaining smooth boundaries.

Comment: Stakanovist ! ;-)

Comment: Thanks @marmot. I will study the code and see what I can do.

Comment: @HoudaAraj What you could do is to accept the answers you got on your previous questions. Please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). I had a look at these answers, and I really believe you should honor these by accepting them and, if you did not already do this, upvote them. (I don't care what you do with this answer.)